# California requesting extradition of fugitives from a foreign country

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, extradition

By reading up on the law stackexchange website, I know that for California to seek extradition of any fugitives from a foreign country, it needs to go through the State Department and the Department of Justice.

But what happens if the alleged crime is not a crime under federal law? Would the federal agencies refuse to pass on the extradition request to the intended foreign governments?

In general, what are the laws, regulations, guidelines regarding whether or not to send the extradition request when a fugitive is solely wanted by California?

In this question, California can be any other US state.

Answer (score 2):

> But what happens if the alleged crime is not a crime under federal law?

The state asks the Federal government to pursue [extradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extradition_law_in_the_United_States#Extradition_to_the_United_States).

> Would the federal agencies refuse to pass on the extradition request to the intended foreign governments?

Generally not but the would assess the merits of making the request - they don’t do so if they believe they are unlikely to be successful. Limited resources, diplomatic considerations etc.

> In general, what are the laws, regulations, guidelines regarding whether or not to send the extradition request when a fugitive is solely wanted by California?

The US government negotiated with the foreign government on behalf of the state.

Comment: "The state asks the Federal government to pursue extradition." And US extradition treaties generally have language to prevent this from screwing up dual criminality analysis.